# Are there only finitely many $m$ such that $m$ is the number of elliptic curves with a given conductor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be the map sending $n$ to the number of isomorphism classes of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ with conductor $n$.

Is $f(\mathbb{N})$ finite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finiteness of elliptic curves of a given conductor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107287/finiteness-of-elliptic-curves-of-a-given-conductor)

Comment: No that's a different one. There it's said that $f$ is well-defined while I'm asking if $f(\mathbb{N})$ is finite.

Comment: Ah I see, I wasn't careful in reading. I retracted my close vote but will keep the comment above for reference

Comment: Related question, but with no conclusive answer: https://mathoverflow.net/q/350291/30186

Answer (score 16):

The answer is no. Indeed, counterexamples are given by Mordell curves $E_d:y^2=x^3+d$, where $d$ is a sixth-power-free integer. These curves are pairwise non-isomorphic over $\mathbb Q$. Furthermore, this Weierstrass equation is minimal, which implies $E_d$ has additive reduction at all primes dividing $d$. Therefore the conductor of $E_d$ has the form $2^a3^b\prod_{p\mid d,p>3}p^2$, where $a,b$ range over finitely many possibilities (at most $24$ in this case if memory serves me right). But if we take $d$ to range over integers of the form $p_1^{e_1}\dots p_k^{e_k}$ where $1\leq e_i\leq 5$, we get $5^k$ curves with the same conductor give or take powers of $2,3$, and hence in total at least $5^k/24$ curves with the same conductor.

Of course, these curves all arise as twists of a single curve, and it could be interesting to ask for nontrivial examples where this doesn't hold. Alternatively we could restrict to squarefree conductors, that is semistable elliptic curves.